# Tailwind will not purge

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to get tailwind to purge CSS on my files, but I can't seem to get it working.

To provide some context, I have a public folder that contains a CSS folder and a views folder. I am trying to purge the single ejs file within the views folder.

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 purge: {
  enabled: true,
  content: ['./public/**/*.ejs']
 },
 theme: {},
 variants: {},
 plugins: [],
}
```

Here is my postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
  tailwindcss: {},
  autoprefixer: {},
 }
}
```

Here is my script I'm running from my package.json

```
    "tw-prod": "tailwind build public/css/tailwind.css -o public/css/style.css"
```

I have also tried the following, without any luck

```
"tw-prod": "postcss public/css/tailwind.css -o public/css/style.css"
```

And finally here is some code from my app.js which may help diagnose my problem

```
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public/views'));
```

Each time I run the build script, the size of the stylesheet remains the same at 3.81mb.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, please?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running the script with `NODE_ENV=production`?
like

```sh
NODE_ENV=production npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css
```

EDIT:
Instead of running

```sh
"tw-prod": "tailwind build public/css/tailwind.css -o public/css/style.css"
```

run this

```sh
"tw-prod": "NODE_ENV=production tailwind build public/css/tailwind.css -o public/css/style.css"
```

Tailwind requires the `NODE_ENV` to be set for the purge function to kick in and do its job.

Read more about this [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#building-for-production)

PS: BTS postcss file now comes configured by default that I guess takes care of this purging functionality

Comment: adding `NODE_ENV=production` to my tailwind build fixed the issue. It went from 4MB to 41KB! Thanks mate!